# How to merge the SSD NVMe storages with the root in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

There is an instance on AWS. Below is a screenshot showing that `/dev/root` is 7.6 GB with the usage of 100% but the NVMe shows 116 GB available.

[image]

My question: is there any way that filesystem `/dev/nvme1n1` merged with `/dev/root` so the amount of `root` space is extended? If not, any suggestions to work around this?

More info: the instance comes with 1 x 125 NVMe SSD by default so it doesn't make sense to me to buy additional storage for the root (/).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Even if technically possible, you wouldn't want to. They are two different storage types with the nvme one being ephemeral (all data is lost on shutdown).

Comment: You could launch an instance with an instance store backed volume and only use the instance store on the device, assuming you're ok with the trade offs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no sense because /dev/nvme1n1 is Instance Storage volume and its content will not survive stop of the EC2 instance (unlike your 8GB root EBS volume which is durable).

Perhaps the easiest option for you is to resize the root EBS volume and then resize the filesystem (elastic EBS volumes allow live resize).

If you still want to combine root EBS and Instance Storage volumes, you probably may achieve that via LVM, but IMO that's a bad idea from durability and performance POV.